# How to add specified images for buttons clicked in java script node/html?(I am new)

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I am having troubles in adding images to my adventure game.
I am doing this for school. I got the information down, but I am stuck in trying to add specific images so they can show up once I press the button to progress the story.
Sorry if how I describe my problem comes across confusing...

The code shows up fine. All I want to do is add some images to my game.

Here's a link to the code,  and here's the script within the HTML. I am not sure if I am doing it right.

EDIT:: (UPDATED LINK TO JSFIDDLE)

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YewtreeStudio/3zsgdp9f/22/)

```
var db = [

{

  "question": "<br><b> From where he stands, there is a door way. To the left, there is a mirror.</b>",
  "answers": [{
      "title": "Go through the doorway.",
      "response": 1
    },
    {
      "title": "Look into the mirror.",
      "response": 2
    }
  ]

}, {

  "question": "<b> As he was approaching the doorway, he asked himself: <i> Why Would I want to do that?</i></b>",

  "answers": [

    {
      "title": "Go back.",
      "response": 0
    }
  ]
},
{
  "question": "<b>The man looks at himself and sees that he appear to be a blue-haired man. For some reason, the man feels unsettled with the reflection that's being projected.</b>",
  "answers": [{
    "title": "Check pockets",
    "response": 3
  }]
},
{
  "question": "<b>In his pockets there's a wallet, small notebook and a watch. The Watch isn't working, so he puts the watch away. Both of the objects has the name <i> Dimitri Zimmerman </i> written on them. The man now remembers his name.</b>",
  "answers": [{
      "title": "Check wallet.",
      "response": 4
    },
    {
      "title": "Check the note-book.",
      "response": 6
    }
  ]
},

{
  "question": "<b> Dimitri opened the wallet and quickly figured out as to why he felt this disembodied feeling when faced with the refection. Dimitri's appearance changed entirely. The ID photo presents a more mundane appearance than the demonic appearance that now presents him. Dimitri also finds out he's a Detective by examining his ID.</b>",
  "answers": [{
    "title": "Check the note-book.",
    "response": 5
  } ]
},
{
  "question": "<b> While putting the wallet back in his pocket, Dimitri began flipping through the pages.</b>",
  "answers": [
    {
      "title": "...How odd",
      "response": 6
    }
  ]
},

{
  "question": "<b>There appears to be some sort of writing within the pages that Dimitri can't comprehend. Briskly he raffled through the pages to find anything legible.</b>",
  "answers": [{
    "title": "Keep Looking",
    "response": 7
  }]
},
{
  "question": "<b> Dimitri continue to flip through the illegable pages. On the last page you are able read what's written.</b>",

  "answers": [

    {
      "title": "Read.",
      "response": 8
    }]
},

{
  "question": "<b> Crudely written in red-ink, it read:<br> <i> I have gone beyond than any mortal should, I might lose my mind or something once making contact with the Black Lodge... Remember I am looking for ----- R---. I must not forget why I am here, so I have this notebook to remember if I were to become lost. I must apprehend that murder.</i> Where the name should be displayed, it's the same incoherent scribbles on the pages before.</b>",

  "answers": [
    {
      "title": "Put the note-book away.",
      "response": 9
    }]
},

{
  "question": " <b> After putting the notebook away, Dimitri stepped away from the mirror and looked over to the doorway, still hazed with the details of why he is here. All that Dimitri knows that he's a Detective who's after a murder.</b>",
  "answers": [

    {
      "title": "Leave the room.",
      "response": 10
    }]
},
{
  "question": "<b>To be Continued...</b>",
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add different image for different question, you can modify the json as below.

Can add the individual image path to each json, or can ignore if no need of image for any question.

```
    if(db[currentLocation].img){
        document.getElementById("img").src = db[currentLocation].img
    }else{
        document.getElementById("img").src = ''
    }
```

overall code

```
function pictureChange() {
    document.getElementById("theImage").src = "http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png";
}
var db = [



    {

        "question": "<br><b> From where he stands, there is a door way. To the left, there is a mirror.</b>",
        "answers": [{
            "title": "Go through the doorway.",
            "response": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "Look into the mirror.",
            "response": 2
        },
        ]

    }, {

        "question": "<b> As he was approaching the doorway, he asked himself: <i> Why Would I want to do that?</i></b>",
        "img": "http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png",
        "answers": [

            {
                "title": "Go back.",
                "response": 0
            },

        ]
    },

    {
        "question": "<b>The man looks at himself and sees that he appear to be a blue-haired man. For some reason the man feels unsettled with the reflection that's being projected.</b>",
        "img": "http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png",
        "answers": [{
            "title": "Check pockets",
            "response": 3
        }]
    },
    {
        "question": "<b>In his pockets there's a wallet, small note-book and a watch. The Watch isn't working, so he puts the watch away. Both of the objects has the name <i> Dimitri Zimmerman </i> written on them. The man now remembers his name.</b>",
        "answers": [{
            "title": "Check wallet.",
            "response": 4
        },
        {
            "title": "Check the note-book.",
            "response": 6
        },
        ]
    },

    {
        "question": "<b> Dimitri opened the wallet and quickly figured out as to why he felt this disembodied feeling when faced with the refection. Dimitri's appearance changed entirely. The ID photo presents a more mundane appearance than the demonic appearance that now presents him. Dimitri also finds out he's a Detective by examining his ID.</b>",
        "answers": [{
            "title": "Check the note-book.",
            "response": 5
        },]
    },

    {
        "question": "<b> While putting the wallet back in his pocket, Dimitri began flipping through the pages.</b>",
        "answers": [

            {
                "title": "...How odd",
                "response": 6
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        "question": "<b>There appears to be some sort of writing with in the pages that Dimitri can't comprehend. Briskly he raffled through the pages to find anything legable.</b>",
        "answers": [{
            "title": "Keep Looking",
            "response": 7
        },]
    },
    {
        "question": "<b> Dimitri continue to flip through the illegable pages. On the last page you are able read what's written.</b>",
        "answers": [
            {
                "title": "Read.",
                "response": 8
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        "question": "<b> Crudely written in red-ink, it read:<br> <i> I have gone beyond than any mortal should, I might lose my mind or something once making contact with the Black Lodge... Remember I am looking for ----- R---. I must not forget why I am here, so I have this note-book to remember if I were to become lost. I must apprehend that murder.</i> Where the name should be displayed, it's the same incohearent scribbles on the pages before.</b>",

        "answers": [

            {
                "title": "Put the note-book away.",
                "response": 9
            },

        ]


    },

    {
        "question": " <b> After putting the note book away, Dimitri stepped away from the mirror and looked over to the doorway, still hazed with the details of why he is here. All that Dimitri knows that he's a Detective who's after a murder.</b>",
        "img": "http://31.media.tumblr.com/fca646cd8fe87906e605ad7e8d039903/tumblr_mmoz4fWT6U1soh1p8o1_500.png",
        "answers": [

            {
                "title": "Leave the room.",
                "response": 10
            },

        ]



    },


    {
        "question": "<b>To be Continued...</b>",


    },


];


var currentLocation = 0;

window.printCurrentLocation = function () {

    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = db[currentLocation].question;
    debugger;
    if (db[currentLocation].img) {
        document.getElementById("img").src = db[currentLocation].img
    } else {
        document.getElementById("img").src = ''
    }
    var answers = "";
    for (var i = 0, l = db[currentLocation].answers.length; i < l; i++) {
        answers += "<p><button onclick='setLocation(" + db[currentLocation].answers[i].response + ")'>" + db[currentLocation].answers[i].title + "</button></p>";
    }
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = answers;
}

window.setLocation = function (num) {
    currentLocation = num;
    window.printCurrentLocation();
}

window.printCurrentLocation();
```

Comment: Thank you! I placed in the prompt and the questions are not vanishing. But I am still facing a problem with the images not changing after pressing the button/"title". Is there something I have to do in the HTML? Also, would it matter if one of the images I want to present is a different format (.gif) or should I make all the images the same format?

Comment: You have to replace
<div id="img"></div>

to

<div><img src='' id="img" /></div>
in order to load the image.

In the JSON, you can give url of any picture with various format, it shouldn't have to same format. But make sure the picture link is active.


https://jsfiddle.net/hkfb8c7s/1/

the fiddle contain images of gif, jpg, png included in json

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thank you!